# Insert a bit value into MariaDB with PDO prepared statement

Tags: php, pdo, mariadb

I'm trying to set a (single) bit field to true / 1 in MariaDB > 10.2.4.

With older versions MariaDB gave a warning but updated the record. Now I keep getting

> 1406 / Data too long for column ...".

If I hardcode the statement with something like

```
$sql .= ', active_flag = true';
```

it works but as a bound value I can't find a way. All the following don't work:

```
$value_array[] = 1;
$value_array[] = true;
$value_array[] = '1';
$value_array[] = 'b`1`';
$value_array[] = 'true';
```

Any idea?

Comment: Please show the query and how you're trying to use the bound variable.

Comment: I figured it out.
You cannot bind the value but you can hardcode it into the query.
So instead of creating placeholders for the bit values like
$keyplaceholder_array[] = $key . '=?' / $value_array[] = $value
I put the value into the placeholder array
$keyplaceholder_array[] = $key . '=true'
and skip the value_array element. Similar with inserts.